# How to style select crossbrowser

Tags: css, select, cross-browser, styling

Hi I'm searching for a solution, to have a crossbrowser style for my select. At the moment, my select (dropdown) looks different in chrome, firefox, safari and IE. I found some questions, but they didn't really helped me. Has someone an idea how to do this? The goal is, that my select looks same in every browser.

I tried this css:

```
    select {
        transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s;
        background: transparent;
        border: 1px solid $BORDER_COLOR;
        outline: 0;
        padding: 5px;

        -webkit-user-select: none;
        -moz-user-select: -moz-none;
        -ms-user-select: none;
        user-select: none;

        -webkit-appearance: none;
        -moz-appearance: radio-container;
        appearance: none;

        background: url("../../assets/images/arrow.svg") no-repeat center right;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about that ? http://jsfiddle.net/jphase/quqnmoun/
From : http://robido.com/css/pure-css-select-dropdown-style-override-the-default-select-dropdown-styles-with-css/

It uses these selectors

```
select::-ms-expand
select:-moz-focusring
```

It says it works for Chrome 45.x, Firefox 41.x, and Internet Explorer 11.x. But not tested for older version

Comment: This is really cool and I can use it - thank you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option is not using `select`s. You can build a dropdown, as ibm does:

http://www.ibm.com/design/language/resources/animation-library/ios-drop-down

Use a `ul` instead. And go cross-browser all the way.

But usually, when I have to do this, I wrap it in a div and I add a pseudo-element to that parent hiding the carrot. Make sure you give a `height` (not `line-height`) to the `select` element. And then you control the `height` of the pseudo-element.